# ng-selected true for an option of selectbox, but showing incorrect option tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a selectbox with `ng-selected` on `ng-repeat` options.

```
<div class="imageselectbox">
    <select class="form-control" value="selectedItem" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-change="onItemSelected()" kdi-scroll-to kdi-offset-of={{offsetOf}} >
        <option ng-repeat="item in items" value="{{item.imageValue}}" data-iconurl="{{item.imageDataURI}}" 
                ng-selected='{{selectedItem == item.imageValue}}'></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

The DOM shows `ng-selected="true"` on the correct option tag, but the dropdown shows the first value. Does anybody know the reason?

Comment: Can you include the relevant code (html)?

Comment: I think type of selectedItem and item.imageValue may be difference. use same type for both.

Comment: @DayachandPatel the type are same. I read in some other articles that ng-selected used with ng-repeat sometimes behaves incorrectly, suggesting to use ng-options. But in my case i cannot use ng-options.